# kendo ui toolbar - how to select button programmatically

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

Is there an equivalent method to 'getSelectedFromGroup' that SETS a certain button in a button group please?

If I set a button as default using

```
{ type: "button", id: "Thought", text: "Thought", togglable: true, group: "buttonGroup", selected: true },

{ type: "button", id: "Speech", text: "Speech", togglable: true, group: "buttonGroup" },
```

.. It doesn't change when I do..

```
...

Toolbar.toggle("#Speech", true);

...
```

However things work OK if I don't initially set the default button using  [...button... , selected: true"]

If I don't set a default button, my code gives errors. If I do set a default button, I cannot later change it in code as there doesn't appear to be a method to do that.

So, how do I change the selected button in a button group using code?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the op is referring to Kendo UI for Angular or not. If so, the only way I could find to do this was via ViewChild Button directives on each button. I only had two so wasn't that arduous but if your buttons are programmatically created, then this won't work.

Component.ts

```
  @ViewChild("currentButton", { read: ButtonDirective }) public currentButton!: ButtonDirective;
  @ViewChild("historyButton", { read: ButtonDirective }) public historyButton!: ButtonDirective;

  public toCurrent(isTrue: boolean) {
    if (isTrue) {
      DoSomething();
    }
  }

  public toHistory(isTrue: boolean) {
    if (isTrue) {
      DoSomethingElse();
    }
  }
```

Component.html

```
<kendo-buttongroup selection="single">
          <button          
            class="btn btn--secondary"
            kendoButton
            #currentButton
            [toggleable]="true"
            [selected]="true"
            (selectedChange)="toCurrent($event)"
          >
            <span><span class="k-icon k-i-check-circle"></span>Current</span>
          </button>
          <button          
            class="btn btn--secondary"
            kendoButton            
            #historyButton
            [toggleable]="true"
            [selected]="false"
            (selectedChange)="toHistory($event)"
          >
            <span><span class="k-icon k-i-clock"></span>History</span>
          </button>
        </kendo-buttongroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/EvIxe) demo how you can change grid toolbar programmatically

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.